# How to apply adobe icc profiles to an image using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert a rgb image to cmyk using profiles I downloaded from the adobe website.

The command I am using is as follow:

> convert Playbook.jpg -profile CoatedFOGRA27.icc cmyk_playbook.jpg

When I try to open the output image on photoshop, **I get a error that it's impossible to use the ICC profile incorporated, because the profile ICC is incorrect. The profile will be ignored.**

When I check the -verbose of the image using the identity command I get the colorspace as sRGB. I could see that the color profiles were added to the image. *But I don't understand how adobe ps does it differently. Adding a -colorspace CMYK will change the colorspace from -sRGB to CMYK, but the results are not good. The colors in the output are not even close to the real input.*

```
C:\test\profile>magick identify -verbose cmyk_playbook.jpg
Image: cmyk_playbook.jpg
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 969x301+0+0
Resolution: 72x72
Print size: 13.4583x4.18056
Units: PixelsPerInch
Type: TrueColor
Endianess: Undefined
**Colorspace: sRGB**
icc:copyright: Copyright 2004-2007 Adobe Systems Incorporated
icc:description: Coated FOGRA27 (ISO 12647-2:2004)
icc:manufacturer: Coated FOGRA27 (ISO 12647-2:2004)
icc:model: Coated FOGRA27 (ISO 12647-2:2004)
```

I'm new to icc profiles and any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need any info regarding the test done here. I am referring to a imagemagick usage guide for my tests [imagemagick color profile](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#profiles)

**EDIT 2**
As per Fred's comments, I had better results when I modified imagemagick string to (referred from the imagemagick profile's section)

```
magick convert Playbook.jpg -profile AdobeRGB1998.icc -profile CoatedFOGRA39.icc cmyk_playbook.jpg
```

-verbose of output image at link https://textuploader.com/dvbyp

**EDIT 3**
**Verbose of the input image**

```
> C:\test\profile>magick identify -verbose Playbook.jpg
Image: Playbook.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 969x301+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 13.4583x4.18056
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 291669
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 194.392 (0.762322)
      standard deviation: 83.2222 (0.326362)
      kurtosis: 0.704344
      skewness: -1.52406
      entropy: 0.788734
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 212.207 (0.832184)
      standard deviation: 48.3621 (0.189655)
      kurtosis: 1.86417
      skewness: -1.56849
      entropy: 0.805723
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 212.778 (0.834423)
      standard deviation: 50.177 (0.196772)
      kurtosis: 2.14027
      skewness: -1.61153
      entropy: 0.817837
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 206.459 (0.809643)
      standard deviation: 63.2485 (0.248033)
      kurtosis: 2.77398
      skewness: -1.87528
      entropy: 0.804098
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 969x301+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 99
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2018-09-24T13:58:23+02:00
    date:modify: 2018-09-07T12:10:45+02:00
    exif:ColorSpace: 65535
    exif:DateTime: 2018:05:22 10:58:52
    exif:ExifImageLength: 301
    exif:ExifImageWidth: 969
    exif:ExifOffset: 168
    exif:Orientation: 1
    exif:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:Software: Adobe Photoshop CC (Macintosh)
    exif:thumbnail:Compression: 6
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormat: 306
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 3377
    exif:thumbnail:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:thumbnail:XResolution: 72/1
    exif:thumbnail:YResolution: 72/1
    exif:XResolution: 720000/10000
    exif:YResolution: 720000/10000
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: ca4b1e91d7efa6044dca943ef7bd15b562190d821b86ce25ad55f3150100150e
  Clipping path:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="969" height="301">
<g>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" style="fill:#00000000;stroke:#00000000;stroke-width:0;
stroke-antialiasing:false" d="
M 342 56
L 363 56
L 438 55
L 452 52
L 475 49
L 491 46
L 510 39
L 526 33
L 544 26
L 554 18
C 554 18 557.982 -3.60937 556 -6.00001
C 554.018 -8.39063 527.42 -31.6426 525 -32
C 522.58 -32.3574 455.445 -39.2773 450 -39
C 444.555 -38.7226 388.031 -37.0664 386 -36
C 383.969 -34.9336 345.721 -11.0879 344 -8
C 342.279 -4.9121 332.74 22.6133 333 26
C 333.26 29.3867 342 56 342 56 Z
"/>
</g>
</svg>

  Profiles:
    Profile-8bim: 11730 bytes
    Profile-exif: 3689 bytes
    Profile-iptc: 95 bytes
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      City[1,90]: 0x00000000: 254700                                        -%
      unknown[2,0]:
    Profile-xmp: 1241722 bytes
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 1.458MB
  Number pixels: 292K
  Pixels per second: 4.704MB
  User time: 0.047u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.062
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-4 Q16 x64 2017-03-25 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: If your image is RGB colorspace and already has an (s)RGB profile, then your command would be correct assuming the profile is at the same locations as where you issue your convert command. However, if the image has no profile already, then you need to use two profiles. First add an sRGB,icc profile, then add your CoatedFOGRA27.icc. What is your version of Imagemagick and on what platform? Is your input jpg RGB or CMYK? Can you post a link to your input image or at least show its identify -verbose information?

Comment: @fmw42 : I have uploaded the -verbose at https://textuploader.com/dvbwe , I have selected the link to never expire. But if it's an issue, I will try to find an another option to share.

Comment: @fmw42: I have a question: I don't need to add -colorspace CMYK to the mixture right,  "magick convert Playbook.jpg +profile icm -profile AdobeRGB1998.icc -profile CoatedFOGRA39.icc cmyk_playbook.jpg"

Comment: @everyone, how do I identify if it has a rgb profile, I couldn't see anything of that sort in the verbose of my input file.

Comment: If it does not show in the verbose information, then there is not likely a color profile. You could post the verbose information for your input, if you want me to review it. So you should only need to use one CMYK profile to convert from RGB to CMYK. If you post your image, I can try to convert it using the profile. NOTE that in Imagemagick 7, you should not use magick convert. Simply use magick. What is your Imagemagick version and platform? In your new command you stripped any icm profiles, but you could have an icc profile.

Comment: Hi @fmw42, Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-4 Q16. Windows based. I am trying to do an automation to convert an image to rgb/cmyk based on the profile. But I am having trouble identifying the profile of an image. I'm going to post the entire verbose for the image on the question for your reference.

Comment: @fmw42, i found an old post of yours on the imagemagick forum, which had the command "identify -format %[profiles] ". When I use this I get the string output {8bim,exif,iptc,xmp} for the input, do you have a technique to identify for any random rgb/cmyk profile in the image?

Comment: `@Binoy Cherian` I am not sure what you mean by "identify". Was that command not what you wanted?  See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#profiles and https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php. In the latter, there are -format "%[profile:icc]" info: and -format "%[profile:icm]" info: which will give you details about icc and icm color profiles.

Comment: @fmw42, it works.